# Bulding a fix length string with values passed using the length/position in pl/sql

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am writing a function which would build a fix a length empty string with value in a fix length string. for e.g. 
I have a string of length 1000. When I pass string 'ABC' of length 5 with position 50, the function puts 'ABC' at 50th position of that fixed length string and pads 2 char with ' '.
I have managed to write it using regexp_replace. However I need it which doesnt use regexp_replace as it seems very slow in processing.
This function will be called in batch processing to build message string to be passed to other interface.

```
create or replace function insert_string(i_value varchar2, i_length number, i_position number) return varchar2
is
fix_string varchar2(1000) := ' ';
begin
    fix_string := rpad(fix_string,1000,' ');
    fix_string := regexp_replace(fix_string,'.{'||i_length ||'}',rpad(i_value,i_length,' '),i_position,1);
    return fix_string;
end;
```

Comment: Can't you use LPAD y RPAD to build the fixed string out of the i_value string?

Comment: This function will take many different values as an argument and will build string, e.g.
string ;=  insert_string('ZXCS',1,100);
string := insert_string('ABC',150,5);
string := insert_string('PQERS',890,9);

likewise....the end result will have all the values placed in specific position and paddd according to length.

Comment: Hi can you show us sample data and expected output for us to visualize properly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ideally, it would replace....as a fixed length blank string needs to be built with values passed to it...so if an empty string of size 1000 is there, then what ever value is passsed with length and position, replaces the fixed length string with the value.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_string(i_value VARCHAR2, i_length NUMBER, i_position NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
   RETURN RPAD(LPAD(i_value, i_position + LENGTH(i_value) - 1), i_length);
END;
```

Comment: I couldnt get it. How would RPAD build a string?
there will be several values to be sort of merged in a string based on the position given....

Comment: What values? Are there any other values different from i_value?

Comment: the intention is to call the function for number of i_values, which will be used to build  a string, to be passed to an interface..

Comment: Could you give me an example of something you couldn't get with the rpad version? I think I didn't understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I need  to put this value into a fixed string at specific location, correct. however this operation will be repeated..

fixed_length varchar2(1000);
now I call insert_string, pass  a value, its length and its position...which will put/replace the value to the specifc location in fixed_length string..
again insert_string will be called for different value, different position.hence fixed_length changed with 2 values, at differnt position.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. You should have an in-out parameter then, right?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what youve been trying to do/say but in case it is, ive added another parameter which will contain the source string. Without the string inside the function, its hard to manipulate values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INSERT_STRING(source_string VARCHAR2,
                                         input_string VARCHAR2, 
                                         start_position NUMBER, 
                                          input_len NUMBER) 

RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

 TYPE char_arr IS TABLE OF CHAR(1) INDEX BY pls_integer;
TYPE char_arr2 IS TABLE OF CHAR(1);
source_array char_arr2:= char_arr2();
input_array char_arr;
X NUMBER:=1;
new_string VARCHAR2(2000);

BEGIN

   FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(source_string) -- converts the source string to array
    LOOP
    source_array.extend;
    source_array(i) := substr( source_string, i, 1 );
    END LOOP;
-------------------------------------------------------------------

    FOR j IN 1 .. input_len  -- converts the input string to array with size input_len
    LOOP
    input_array(j) := substr( input_string, j, 1 );
    END LOOP;
-------------------------------------------------------------------
--dbms_output.put_line(input_array(1));

   FOR k IN 1..LENGTH(source_string) -- loop to insert the input_string to the source string
   LOOP
      IF k >= start_position  THEN
          source_array.extend;
           source_array(k) := input_array(X) ;
        x := x+1;
        IF x > input_array.count THEN
        exit;
        end if;
      END IF;

   END LOOP;

   FOR m IN 1 .. LENGTH(source_string) --loop to convert array back to string
    LOOP
        IF source_array(m) is null THEN
            source_array(m) := ' ';
        END IF;

         new_string := new_string||source_array(m);
    END LOOP;

RETURN new_string;

END;
```

Sample:

```
select insert_string('**********', 'ABC', 3, 5) from dual;
```

Output:

```
INSERT_STRING('**********','ABC',3,5)
    **ABC  ***
```

take note.

- > Source string should not be empty.
- > the size of the source string should be greater than the size of the input_string else the excess character from the input will not be inserted in the source string

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will give it a try and see how it works for me!! Thanks  a lot for your time :)